# how to post a looping value of radio button that have dynamics name?

Tags: php

i tried to develop a system that allowing users to answer a quiz that will be generated randomly from a database. the problems now is to mark the quiz. how can i post value of radio button because it has different name.

this is some of my code.
thanks.

```
$selq="SELECT * FROM question WHERE q_subject_kod = '$subkod' AND q_chapter= '$chap' order by RAND() limit $bil ";
    $result=mysql_query($selq);?>

    <form name="quiz" action="mark.php?bil=<?php echo $bil?>&chap=<?php echo $chap?>&action=1&subject=<?php echo $subkod?>" method="post">
<?php

##Cycle through randomly selected questions
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>=0) {
$qi = 1;
$e=0?>
<table name="q" border="1" cellpadding="2"  width="100%">
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<?php
while ($qry = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $idsol=$qry['id'];
    $sol=$qry['q_quest'];
    $jwpn=$qry['q_ranws'];?>
<tr><td><?php echo $qi?></td> <td><?php echo $sol?></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>
A<input type="radio" name="ans.<? echo $e?>" id="<? echo $idsol?>"value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws'];?>" /><?php echo $qry['q_anws'];?><br />
B <input type="radio" name="ans.<? echo $e?>" id="<? echo $idsol?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws1'];?>"  /><?php echo $qry['q_anws1'];?><br />
C <input type="radio" name="ans.<? echo $e?>" id="<? echo $idsol?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws2'];?>"  /><?php echo $qry['q_anws2'];?><br />
D <input type="radio" name="ans.<? echo $e?>" id="<? echo $idsol?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws3'];?>"  /><?php echo $qry['q_anws3'];?><br />
<input type="text" name="val.<? echo $idsol?>" value="<? echo $idsol?>">
</td>
</tr>



<?php
$qi++;
$e++;}}}?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Question, all Radio Buttons need the same name anyhow, and you don't nesecarly need an ID. So that would work just fine:

```
A<input type="radio" name="ans_<? echo $idsol?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws'];?>" /><?php echo $qry['q_anws'];?><br />
B <input type="radio" name="ans_<? echo $idsol?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws1'];?>"  /><?php echo $qry['q_anws1'];?><br />
C <input type="radio" name="ans_<? echo $idsol ?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws2'];?>"  /><?php echo $qry['q_anws2'];?><br />
D <input type="radio" name="ans_ <? echo $idsol?>" value="<?php echo $qry['q_anws3'];?>"  /><?php echo $qry['q_anws3'];?><br />
```

But just for the Matter of principle, try to store the Answers in a different Table then the Questions, this Way every Answer can have his own "id" and you are not limited to 4.

Comment: i need to post its value. how to do it? because name for next question will be different.